# How can i create a function or a loop the rename the columns of 24 dataframes?

Tags: r, data-science

i have 24 dataframes for 24 years of commercial flows and all of them look like this.

```
   t i  j      k          v       q
1 1997 4 12  90930 210.981000 160.433
2 1997 4 12 121190   2.614000   4.187
3 1997 4 20 570110  26.957000   2.500
4 1997 4 31 190211   3.747064  21.613
5 1997 4 31 252329  22.541865 626.000
```

I need to change the names of the variables to the following ones Year, Product, Exporter, Importer, Flow, Quantity for t,i,j,k,v,q respectively.

I'm using the function below but it doesn't save the changes. When i run the code it gives me the output with the new dataframe and the new names of the columns but it is not replaced on the original dataframe.

What I'm looking for is to minimize the quantity of lines wrote to achieve this, so for example doing "BACI1995 <- ChangeNames(BACI1995) BACI1996 <- ChangeNames(BACI1996)"is not an option

```
ChangeNames <- function(x) {
    names(x) <- c("Year", "Product", "Exporter", "Importer", "flow", "Quantity")
    return(x)
}

ChangeNames(BACI1995)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you really want to minimise the number of keystrokes, then consider this one-liner:

```
for (i in 1995:2018) names(.GlobalEnv[[paste0("BACI", i)]]) <- c("Year", "Product", "Exporter", "Importer", "flow", "Quantity")
```

Comment: Thanks,  this is awesome!

Comment: ekoam, will this work if there are other objects in global environment apart from BACI named objects?

Comment: Yes. Here `.GlobalEnv[[paste0("BACI", i)]]` we only select from the .GlobalEnv those objects named as "BACI*". We never touch any other object in the .GlobalEnv. On the other hand, consider a generic for loop, in which the counter `i` is also an object stored in the .GlobalEnv. For each loop the counter modifies itself even if there are other objects in the .GlobalEnv. Don't you think that's similar to the case above? @KarthikS